# How to read dynamic data-id value in js from mustache template?

Tags: javascript, mustache

I am new to mustache templating.

I have created dynamic data-ids carriers_{{name}}_name
in my jsp as below:

```
<div class="gs grid-7of8 pointer cell"><p data-id="carriers_{{name}}_name">{{name}}</p></div>
```

now if i want to do the DOM manipulation in my JS by searching through this data-id. How can i do it? how can i get this dynamic value {{name}} in my JS?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(functoin(){
var $text="#"+$('.cell').find('p').attr('id');
 alert($($text)).html();

})
```

for more then one paragraphs you can use each() statement

```
    $(document).ready(functoin(){
          $('.cell').each('p'){
          var $text="#"+$(this).attr('id');
          alert($($text)).html();

});
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just get the dynamic value in your javascript by fetching the json.